# Must I create an IAM user in order to use AWS CodeCommit?

Tags: git, aws-codecommit

To use AWS CodeCommit, I have created an IAM user attached with policy like AWSCodeCommitFullAccess, and I have generated and downloaded both accessKey and code commit credential(username& password).

After I created a repository in CodeCommit, I realized that whenever I want to run some git command, git prompts a message asking me to input user name/password.

Suppose I have a big team to use the code commit, does it mean I have to let everybody know the accessKey and credential(username& password) of the IAM user? is it secure? can't I use IAM role? Using IAM role I can get accessKey although it expires periodically but I guess code commit will be OK with that. But I notice IAM role does not have way to generate code commit credential(username& password) so I do not know how to use it to run git command.

Besides, every time when I run a git command I need to input code commit credential(username& password) which is not convenient. is there any easy way? like cache the credential?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the AWS CLI Credential Helper [1]. The credential helper can generate the credentials for git dynamically by getting credentials from AWS SDK i.e. through credential chain which could be Environment variable, ~/.aws/credential file or IAM instance profile etc.

So in this case when you don't want to create an IAM user per user, you just give an EC2 instance profile permission to CodeCommit (AWSCodeCommitFullAccess). Then setup the credential helper on this EC2 instance and when using git client, git will authenticate transparently to the user. Details of setup procedure: [1].

Ref:

[1] Setup Steps for HTTPS Connections to AWS CodeCommit Repositories on Windows with the AWS CLI Credential Helper  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-windows.html

Comment: Thanks!. The other way is to copy my ssh public key to IAM ->user -> my CodeCommit user -> security credential -> upload SSH key, this way although I still need to create a permanent IAM user, I do not need to always type my user/password when run git command

Comment: @user389955 Authentication via Instance profile would be the best option if you don't want to expose your IAM User credentials. For this to work, you have to use AWS CLI Credential Helper

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create an IAM User if your Instance profile has CodeCommit permissions. As mentioned in other answer, we can use AWS CLI Credential Helper.

All you need to do to make Code Commit Auth via Instance profile is

1. Make sure aws cli v2 is installed on the EC2
2. Install git on the EC2
3. Configure git to use credential helper

   `git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
   git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true`

You can run git commands from your EC2 to test if the config is working